# Looking to access the color(text value) of a cell of a table in a slide using python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am able to access the text of the cell using cell.text(), however, I was wondering if I could similarly access the color of the cell(hopefully return "Red", "Blue", "Green" etc. etc.)

I tried using the RGBcolor library but was unsuccessful

```
from pptx.dml.color as RGBcolor
prs = Presentation('ARD Project Review Deck_Master (3).pptx')
text_runs = []
colors = []
for slide in prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if shape.has_table:
                tbl = shape.table
                row_count = len(tbl.rows)
                col_count = len(tbl.columns)
                for r in range(0, row_count):
                    for c in range(0, col_count):
                        cell = tbl.cell(r,c)
                        if (cell.fill.type == 1):
                            colors.append(cell.fill.rgbcolor.rgb)

set(colors)
```

I also tried using cell.fill.back_color but that is giving me the below error

```
TypeError: fill type _SolidFill has no background color, call .patterned() first
```

Could not find anything anywhere, I apologize in advance if this has been answered. Thanks!

Comment: Try `cell.fill.fore_color`. It might be counter-intuitive, but a cell filled with a solid color only has a foreground color.

Comment: It returns the address such as


'{<pptx.dml.color.ColorFormat at 0x7f25c9e74f60>}'

Comment: I also tried using fore_color.text but it throws an Attribute Error

AttributeError: 'ColorFormat' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
cell.fill.fore_color.rgb
```

This gives you the RGB value which I put around an if statement to convert to String values of the color